# select returns "No such file or directory"

Tags: c, sockets, select, tcp, errno

I have implemented a client that talks to another server. Both exchange messages using a TCP/IP socket.

I notice that each time the server sends me a message i get the following perror "No such file or directory" on my select call. Whats strange is that the correct bit is set and i am able to read the message from the server, but its annoying to see this error.

The reason i had the retry_interval is in case i lose a connection with the server. In that case i set the retry_interval and i keep retrying forming a session again.

Relevant code from the client on which i see this error message:

```
for (;;)
{
    program_select_to_look_at_right_sockets(&readfds, &maxfds);

    do 
    {
        if (RETRY_TIMER_IS_SET(retry_interval))
        {
            activity = select( maxfds + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , &retry_interval);
            set_retry_timer (&retry_interval);
        }
        else                
            activity = select( maxfds + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);

        perror("main loop select error"); <-- Whenever i get a message from server this select throws an error

    } while (activity < 0 && errno == EINTR);

    if (RETRY_TIMER_IS_SET(retry_interval))
    {
        printf ("Connect RETRY timer to server expired!\n");
        connect_to_server_again();
    }
    else if (FD_ISSET (server_connection_socket, &readfds))
    { 
        /* Even if an error is thrown the code does reach this point which i find somewhat strange */
        printf ("Server sent us a message!\n");
        bytes_read = process_data_from_server();

        if (bytes_read == 0)
        {
            clean_connection_from_server (&readfds);
            set_retry_timer (&retry_interval);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I verified that in program_select_to_look_at_right_sockets i am only adding the server socket that i am listening on (thats unix domain socket -- removed code to avoid making it cluttered) and the client socket with which i am connected to the server -- the one on which the data arrives

Comment: You're unconditionally printing an error message and you're wondering why there is an error message? You should only print an error message *if there is an error.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think `select` is returning that error?  You need to check `select`'s return code to see if there was an error.  More information is here:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html

If you don't check the return code then you don't know if there was an error, and the error printed by perror could be some random thing from a previous function call.

Comment: Thanks David this helped! Upon adding if (activity < 0) perror("main loop select error"); i dont see the offending error message anymore!

Comment: Great!  Would you mind marking my answer as the accepted answer, by clicking on the checkbox to the left?